# Creation complete for Item Renderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, list, flex4.5, itemrenderer

I have a Spark List component with custom Item Renderer. Data provider for the List - Array Collection with 8 elements.
Why creation complete of Item Renderer occurs only 7 times? Although the Array Collection of 8 elements and the List displays 8 objects.
All this leads to errors in data access (data.myParams).

Comment: Are the 8 items displayed at the same time? Isn't there a scrollbar?

Comment: Yes. Thanx, LoremIpsum give me right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ItemRenderers are recycled. You should override the *data* accessors of your itemRenderer and then perform any action you want, as it is the moment your renderer gets data from the list.

There : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html

Comment: override public function set data(value:Object):void {      
     if(value != null)  {
      super.data = value;
      //my data here
     }   
     dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE));
    }